# Image Recognition Intro: Identifying obects on googlemaps

Tags: c#, image-recognition

I know, already so many 'how to compare 2 images' question out there.
I have looked at many and could not find anything relevant to my particular need - I apologize if I have missed something I should not have !

So,
Firstly, I am familiar with c#, completely unfamiliar with image processing and recognition.
Secondly, I am not looking for someone to hand me a complete answer, simply seeking to point myself in the right direction to tackle the job in hand.

Objective:
I am seeking to identify the location of certain physical structures on images taken from google maps.
Unfortunately I cannot tell or show what those structures are, but we can use an example, let's say it's a round swimming pool.
Key point maybe, I'm looking to find a small object 'within' a large image.

Considering I've never tackled image processing before, I appear to be completely over whelmed with options of libraries available, names and terminology of functions and capabilities... and I seem to be spending hours going down dead end avenues.
A lot of reading seems to be comparing 1 image with another, rather than an image 'within' an image.

So far AForge & Open CV are the obvious names that have been seen a lot .. but I really can't work out which of them will do this specific job.

Simply, could someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction to get started?
I'm really trying to narrow reading down to subject matter that is relevant to my case.

- Basic Principles
- Libraries with the required capability.

Any guidance much appreciated.

Many Thanks
Simon

Comment: take a look at "opencv" and its C# wrapper "opencvsharp"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect shapes for example, you can use opencv.
Unfortunately opencv is written in c++ and you would have to write your wrapper.
Instead you can use EmguCV. Try to look at this: [link](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp)